# Merging 2 Lists

Tags: c#, collections, .net-3.5

For example I have these two lists:

```
List<string> firstName = new List<string>();
List<string> lastName = new List<string>();
```

How can I concatenate firstName[0] and lastName[0], firstName[1] and lastName[1], etc and put it in a new list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) from LINQ:

```
var names = firstName.Zip(lastName, (first, last) => first + " " + last)
                     .ToList();
```

(This isn't really *concatenating* the two lists. It's combining them element-wise, but that's not really the same thing.)

EDIT: If you're using .NET 3.5, you can include the `Zip` method yourself - [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx) on it has sample code.

Comment: What if I want to put the result to a new list? Is it possible?

Comment: @ChrisN.P.: That *does* put the result in a new list - that's why there's a `ToList` call.

Comment: I tried this and I got an error: "Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Zip' and no extension method 'Zip' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\ChrisN.P\My Files\My Files\C#\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 24 30 ConsoleApplication1
"

Comment: I'm using System.Linq.

Comment: @ChrisN.P.: It should be fine if you're using .NET 4 or higher. Which version of .NET *are* you using?

Comment: @ChrisN.P.: That would explain it - see my edit. (In the future, if you're using a pretty old version of a platform, it's usually worth saying so in the question.)

Comment: Alright thanks! (Though I'm not sure if .net 3.5 is really that old) :)

Comment: @ChrisN.P.: Well its successor came out over three years ago (April 2010) which makes it *pretty* old in my view...

Comment: You have a point there. Well, this works for me now thank you Jon. Cheers! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Linq Concat and ToList methods

var lists = firstname.Concat(lastname).ToList();